# KnockoutJS `with` binding and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

For some reason my code is generating the error below in IE8, but not in any of the normal browsers.

```
SCRIPT5022: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: 'logoSrc' is undefined;
Bindings value: 'attr': { 'src': logoSrc }
```

I confirmed that the logoSrc property is indeed defined, even in IE8, right before binding, but still it fails.  And disabling the binding to logoSrc just causes the next binding in line to fail.

The html is below.  I know I've used a with binding before, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem, and the html seems to be properly closed.

```
<div data-bind="visible: mode() === 'print'" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- ko with: printVm -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="pull-right" style="width:140px;height:60px;overflow:hidden;">
                    <img data-bind="'attr': { 'src': logoSrc }" src="" />
                </div>
                <h2>Invoice Statement - <span data-bind="text: itemZeroClientName"></span></h2>
            </div>
            <strong>Invoice number:</strong> <span data-bind="text: invoiceId"></span>
            <strong>Invoice date:</strong> <span data-bind="text: userInfo().invoiceDateDisplay"></span>
            <strong>Client number:</strong> <span data-bind="text: itemZeroClientId">22365</span>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 cr-tablet6 cr-phone6">
            <h4>Billed by <span data-bind="text: companyNameDisplay"></span></h4>
            <span data-bind="html: companyInfo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 cr-tablet6 cr-phone6">
            <h4>Billed to</h4>
            <span data-bind="html: clientInfoDisplay"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <hr />
            <table id="printInvoiceTable" class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="date">Date</th>
                    <th class="name">Provider</th>
                    <th class="code">Proc Code</th>
                    <th class="location">Location</th>
                    <th class="time">Hours</th>
                    <th class="units">Units</th>
                    <th class="charge">Charges</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: dateDisplay"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: orgName"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: procedureCodeString"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
                        <td class="formatted-number" data-bind="text: timeWorkedHrs"></td>
                        <td class="formatted-number" data-bind="text: (unitsOfService() || 0).toFixed(2)"></td>
                        <td class="formatted-currency" data-bind="text: (clientCharges() || 0).toFixed(2)"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="formatted-number" data-bind="text: totalWorkedHours"></td>
                        <td class="formatted-number" data-bind="text: totalUnitsOfService"></td>
                        <td class="formatted-currency" data-bind="text: totalClientRate"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: The [attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) doesn't use quotes on the property, and no binding uses quotes on the binding name. It should look like this: `<img data-bind="attr: { src: logoSrc }" src="" />`

Comment: Also, can you post your viewmodel code, the `with` binding looks fine.

Comment: @Tyrsius - view model code is a bit huge - I'll see if I can repro with a simple fiddle.  Also, the attr binding is fine with or without quotes.  In fact, if you opt to use `attr` to bind to the `class` property (even though css binding would do the same) you *have* to put quotes around the word `class`, else IE8 errors out.

Comment: Could [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/VXkPGfhyyt0) have something to do with it? (btw... i can't actually test this, i don't have an IE8 at hand)

Comment: @Grim - it has everything to do with that issue.  I moved my with binding from the html comment up into the parent div, and all is well.  Please make that an answer, and I'll score you some rep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, it seems the issue is with IE8 removing comments (and thus virtual bindings in some conditions) and has been [reported on the knockout forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/VXkPGfhyyt0)

Comment: I'd like to throw in a little caution about mixing `with` and other bindings on the same element. If have `visible: mode() === 'print', with: printVm`, whenever `mode` changes, the `with` binding is also updated and re-renders the entire contents of that element. See http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues using with and jquery file upload in IE8. I also had issues with comments and was able to fix it by escaping the comment condition.  the knockout webpage mentions this warning.